# Java: How to get FFT bands from realtime Microphone Input

Tags: java, audio, fft, microphone

I'm trying to write a JAVA app that will analyse realtime input from a microphone, and do some FFT analysis, I don't know where to begin, i was googling a bit and found nothing really helpful..

Comment: Search for JTransforms right here on StackOverflow.

Comment: Here is some links:
[1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/sound/capturing.html)

[2](https://sites.google.com/site/piotrwendykier/software/jtransforms)

[3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4364823/how-do-i-obtain-the-frequencies-of-each-value-in-an-fft)

[4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5010261/power-spectral-density-from-jtransforms-doublefft-1d)

[5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49097889/how-to-calculate-the-decibel-of-audio-signal-and-record-the-audio-in-java/49140108#49140108)
Please try to post a specific question!